# Post.php is blocked by server? How to unblock?

Tags: wp-admin

I have a weird issue here, where action on classic editor posts such as: save as draft, preview and update lead to a weird error as follow: XMLHttpRequest: Nätverksfel 0x2eff - and of course screen goes offline.
What might be causing the issue, and how can I solve it?
Thanks a million in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your WP is the latest version and that your server is using a newer PHP version. Additionally deactivate all plugins and try testing your posts again. If that fails contact your hosting provider regarding that issue as it may be a restriction on the server.